# How to convert complex c# object to Json without &quot; in mvc5

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, json.net

I get result like this

```
{&quot;Label&quot;:&quot;My Second dataset&quot;,&quot;FillColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(151,187,205,0.2)&quot;,&quot;StrokeColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(151,187,205,1)&quot;,&quot;PointColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(151,187,205,1)&quot;,&quot;PointStrokeColor&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;PointHighlightFill&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;PointHighlightStroke&quot;:&quot;rgba(151,187,205,1)&quot;,&quot;Data&quot;:[28.0,48.0,40.0,19.0,86.0,27.0,90.0]};
```

And error is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Wrap the JsonConvert in @Html.Raw. This may cause issues with your HTML though, depending on the characters present in the JSON.

Comment: I want that to be converted like in Var obj1 but I am getting everything in double quotes, which is less likely to work

Comment: Convert the json to a string and do obj.Replace("&quot;",""); ?

Comment: Show us how do you convert and display the JSON

Answer (score 1):

According to [Code Caster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster),s comment

You should wrap your JSON string in @HTML.Raw :

```
@Html.Raw(yourJSON);
```